# Matlab opens new figure in Callback despite hold

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am creating a GUI with MATLAB's GUIDE. Say, the GUI consists of an axis called `axis1`
and a slider called `slider1`. Further say I wanted to plot something (e.g. a box) into `axis1` and change the box's height with the slider.

I tried doing this by adding a listener to the slider like so:

```
hListener = addlistener(handles.slider1,'Value','PostSet',@(src,evnt)boxHeightChange(src,evnt, handles.figure1));
```

in the GUI's opening function. I further defined:

```
function boxHeightChange(src, event, figname)
   handles = guidata(figname);
   % delete "old" box
   delete(handles.plottedHandle);
   % bring axis in focus
    axes(handles.axes1);
   % plot the new box (with changed size)
    hold on; boxHandle = plotTheBox(event.AffectedObject.Value); hold off
    handles.plottedHandle = boxHandle;
    % update saved values
    guidata(figname, handles);
end
```

This works, but always opens a new figure to plot the resizable box into instead of drawing into `handles.axes1`. I do not understand why, since I call `axes(handles.axes1);` and `hold on;`
Any idea that might explain the behavior?

Comment: What is happening in `plotTheBox`? When you step through your code with [the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html), what line spawns the new figure window?

Comment: Hi @excaza: Does not actually matter. I can replace "plotTheBox" with a simple plot3 command like this: hold on; h = plot3(1,1,1); hold off;
And it still opens a new figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post a solution to my own question.

Apparently the Callback of a listener is not declared as a "GUI Callback" which is why the GUI can not be accessed from within `boxHeightChange` if the GUI option "command-line accessibility" is not set to "On".

That means: In GUIDE go to Tools -> GUI options and set "Command-line accessibility" to "On".

Comment: Good to know! You accept your answer so the thread is closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most plotting functions let you pass a name value pair `'Parent', ah` where `ah` specifies the axes to plot on.  I think this is the best way to handle your problem.  Your actual plotting command seems to be wrapped in the `plotTheBox` function, so you will have to pass the axes handle in somehow.

Your plot command will look something like this:

```
plot(a,'Parent',handles.axes1)
```

You solved the problem a different way on your own, but I think you should do it my way because it's more explicit and it's less likely to lead to unforeseen problems.

Comment: in my quick test just now, this option did not work. I will accept my answer until I am proven wrong ;)

Comment: which plotting function does plotTheBox use?